# How to modify view controller after pressing a button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Let's say that if you press the button from the bottom of the screen after typing something in the account text field, you would be required to also enter the password like in the second image.

How should I do this? I don't think that creating a new view controller would be good. So, should I somehow modify the same view controller?

How could I add the new password text field under the account text field?

Keep in mind that they are still centered. Hiding and unhiding wouldn't work in this case and I also need to modify more things than only adding that text field.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to hide the textfield first time... after you click the button you need to show textfield. You also need to set height constraints constant value programmatically.

Comment: I think you have taken two different view and added textfields and label into it. at very first time you need to hide first view and also need to set its constraints value to 0 programmatically by crating outlet of height constraints. Then after entering text into account textfield and clicking on button you need to show the second view and then you need to update constraint constant value of that view. still if you have any queries please feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

First, create a `UIView` with everything you need on them. in this example I will have only two text fields and they are all color coded.

[image]

The view needs to be centered both horizontally and vertically, with width and height. Set identifiler for the height constraint to be updated later. Set the `clip to board` to true so that when we redeuce the height of the view, text fields below will hide. The settings for the view will be like this

[image]

For your text fields, they must have a constant padding to top. In my example, they are set to be in center horizontally, having a constant height, width and padding to opp.

Now, all you need to do is to get the height of the view from code and set the height to show or hide the text fields.

```
var flag = true

@IBAction func click(_ sender: Any) {
    if flag {
        flag = false
        let filteredConstraints = theView.constraints.filter { $0.identifier == "viewHeight" }
        if let heightConstraint = filteredConstraints.first {
            heightConstraint.constant = 60
        }
    } else {
        flag = true
        let filteredConstraints = theView.constraints.filter { $0.identifier == "viewHeight" }
        if let heightConstraint = filteredConstraints.first {
            heightConstraint.constant = 128
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code running in simulater.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

another option is you can make tableView at Center, you need to create tableview height constraint outlet,

then you can maintain a counter how many time you want to add View, the counter should be return in tableView `numberOfRowsInSection`,
and you can make this view in Prototype Cell or using NIB, then just adjust header label text, textField placeholder and text on specific cell index,

when you increase or decrease counter update tableView Constraint, example you have a cell height as 50, in first case when you have on cell in tableView, you can set your tableView height constraint's constant as 50, when cells are two the 100 and so on.....

I think it's a simple logic